# How to write multiobjective function in Gurobi?

Tags: python, model, gurobi

I am working with multi-objective functionality of Gurobi 7.0, I am having two objective functions:

1. First minimizes the summation of product of Decision Variable with coefficient matrix-1
2. Second minimizes the summation of product of Decision Variable with coefficient matrix-2

I am using hierarchical or lexicographic approach, in which i set a priority for each objective, and optimize in priority order.
I can not use `model.setObjective()` function here because I will not be able to specify the objective function number and model will get confused. How can I write both of the objective functions?

Comment: Link for 'Gurobi' optimizer (a commercial product): www.gurobi.com.  If you do not get answer here, try their support group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gurobi

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Okay, Thanks!

Comment: Read this: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/multiple_objectives.html, and write some code then update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've been testing this feature.

The documentation is not too much clear about the way we must set the objective functions. However, I did the following:

- Define Variables associated with the objective function (cost etc.)
- Then I changed the number of objectives `m.NumObj = 3`
- Set the parameters for each objectives.

  ```
  m.setParam(GRB.Param.ObjNumber, 0)
  m.ObjNPriority = 5
  m.ObjNName = 'Z'
  m.ObjNRelTol = x/10.0
  m.ObjNAbsTol = 0
  Z.objN = 1.0

  m.setParam(GRB.Param.ObjNumber, 1)
  m.ObjNPriority = 4
  m.ObjNName = 'Custo'
  m.ObjNRelTol = x/10.0
  m.ObjNAbsTol = 0
  m.ObjNWeight = -1.0
  Custo.ObjN = 1.0

  m.setParam(GRB.Param.ObjNumber, 2)
  m.ObjNPriority = 10
  m.ObjNName = 'Hop'
  m.ObjNRelTol = x/10.0
  m.ObjNWeight = -1.0
  Hop.ObjN = 1.0
  ```

In my case, there are three objective functions (Z, Custo, Hop).

The parameter `GRB.Param.ObjNumber` is used to change the objective function you are working on.

Another thing that I concluded is that the the number of the objective is defined based on the order we define the variable associated to it (best of my knowledge).

**Details about definition of the objective function**

```
    Custo = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="Custo", obj=1)
    m.update ()

    expr  = []
    for k in xrange (1, KSIZE ):
        expr.append ( quicksum (var_y[ (l[0],l[1],k) ] * links[l][0] for l in links.keys()) )
        expr.append ( quicksum (var_y[ (l[1],l[0],k) ] * links[l][0] for l in links.keys()) )
    m.addConstr (quicksum (expr) == Custo, name= ' custo')
    m.update ()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have two objective functions like this
 'obj1 = quicksum(Matrix2[j][k] * variable1[j,k] for k in range(0,m) for j in range(0,n)) )' 
 'obj2 = quicksum(Matrix2[j][k] * variable1[j,k] for k in range(0,m) for j in range(0,n) )' 
How can I write it in your specified code?

Comment: @JG25 could You share a mathematical formulation for the objectives?

Comment: @JG25 I changed the answer to explain the how to define an objective function based on the cost.